# Can't make flash works correctly (showing current notice message, not previous )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notice

I have standard bug with notices, but I can't make it work correctly.

I'm calling some after_filter to verify if updated data is correct.

Here is code from before filter with notices:

```
    after_filter :verify, :on => :update
     def verify.
     ...
       if account_status == "VERIFIED" 
        flash[:success] = "Your account is verified"
      else 
        flash[:error] = "Sorry, your account is not verified or you entered wrong credentials"
      end
```

so when I use this notices stays on my page after redirection to other page.

When I'm using flash.now[:notice] I lost my messages and they didn't show.

I know, that is standard problem, but I can't find solution that was working for me.

at this moment (before click) my account isn't verified(not correct data).So I'm change them into correct
After I click save it shows me this:
 ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECus0.png  )
but after refreshing page:
  ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwIHe.png )

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a flash notice that doesn't persist you need to do

```
flash.now[:notice] = "..."
```

not `flash[:now]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a flash value to be carried over to another request, use the keep method:

```
def index
  # Will persist all flash values.
  flash.keep
  redirect_to users_url
end
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I've already using notice class to show that data is updated. Does it change something ? I tried this also. MAybe I will supply images to show what I mean.

Comment: never mind the first part, I deleted it, try the keep and read up on the api (link shown) may help

Comment: at this moment (before click) my account isn't verified(not correct data).So I'm change them into correct
After I click save it shows me this:
 ( http://i.imgur.com/j3uw8.png  )
but after refreshing page:
  ( http://i.imgur.com/4EtrL.png )

Comment: Michael Durrant , I don't want to keep it. It showing previous notice message, not current.